# No access after uploading template to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

I am a SharePoint 365 Administrator.  I want to apply a Word template to a new Content type but when I try I get access denied. Then I 'ask' for access en I grant myself access. The strange thing is that yesterday a few times the upload succeeded. But now, I try a different template and it happens again.

I looked at the solution at:

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2112128-access-denied-when-uploading-a-template-to-a-content-type

But that doesn't change the fact that is still cannot upload the file to the site i want to. What is happening here and why does it sometimes work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following powershell to make sure DenyAddAndCustomizePages property value is Disabled:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com

Get-SPOSite https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso | fl
```

Please note that the settings related to custom script may take up to 24 hours to take effect.

You could also check permissions on related site to verify if you have Deny permissions.